# multiple parquet files after pyspark unionByName operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing unionByName to combine 3 py spark data frame in to one data frame.

```
df = df_array[0]
df = df.unionByName(df_array[1])
df = df.unionByName(df_array[2])
part_columns = ["part1","part2", "part3","part4"]
df.write.partitionBy(part_columns).mode('append').parquet(file_path)
```

I expected that it would create one parquet file but it is creating 3 parquet file.
How do i create single parquet file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `coalesce` or `repartition` to achieve this. In this specific case you can achieve one file per partition by

```
df.repartition($"part_columns").write.partitionBy("part_columns").mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked with minor change  
   df.repartition(1).write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode("append").\
            parquet(file_path) . ...I made df.repartition($"part_columns") to 1  is this correct?

Comment: ideally you would wan to `repartition` by the partition column which should ideally give you one file per partition and will parallelize the save operation.